# Change Target Framework Version in ASP.NET Core app

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard

Hi how can I change Target Framework Version in ASP.NET Core app in Visual Studio 2015 ?

I would like to target only "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1".

My project.json frameworks section looks like:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and my xproj file target .NET 4.5.2

```
TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you're trying to achieve here? Do you have a class library or an app?

Comment: Upgrade to VS2017.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful for you to offer a little more color on what it is you're trying to do, but with what you've given here, some thoughts.

First, NETStandard.Library 1.6.1 is a library/package that is installed via NuGet, not a target framework you can run on.  The closest framework you can target is "netstandard1.6", which would imply you're building a class library and not a console or other stand-alone application.  To run that combination, your project.json should look like this (minimally):

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Based on what you've shown in your snippet though, it looks more like your intention was to create a console application, in which case, getting NETStandard.Library 1.6.1 would be done like this (framework section only):

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.1"
        },
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for VS2017 is that you can edit your .csproj file and manually change `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>` to `<TargetFrameworkVersion>netstandard1.6</TargetFrameworkVersion>`.

More information about specifying different target frameworks and switching between them can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks).